# Вложенные циклы for Python

Tags: python, циклы

Доброго времени суток!

```
for i in range(0,4):
    for l in range(0,5):
        print(i, l)
```

У меня получается результат

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
1 0
1 1
1 2
1 3
```

и т.д

а надо чтобы было

```
0 0 1
0 1 2
0 2 3
0 3 4
0 4 5
1 0 6
1 1 7 
1 2 8
1 3 9

...

3 4 20
```

плз. подскажите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам достаточно применить только один цикл:

```
for i in range(1, 21): 
    print((i - 1) // 5, (i - 1) % 5, i)
```

---

Вывод:

> ```
> 0 0 1
> 0 1 2
> 0 2 3
> 0 3 4
> 0 4 5
> 1 0 6
> 1 1 7
> 1 2 8
> 1 3 9
> 1 4 10
> 2 0 11
> 2 1 12
> 2 2 13
> 2 3 14
> 2 4 15
> 3 0 16
> 3 1 17
> 3 2 18
> 3 3 19
> 3 4 20
> ```

---

*Объяснение:*

1. В последнем столбце вы хотели числа от 1 до 20, потому последний параметр функции `print()` тот же самый, как переменная цикла (т.е. просто `i`).
2. В первом и втором столбце вы хотите начинать с нуля, потому выражения в первом и втором столбце начинаются из `(i - 1)`.
3. Теперь, в первом столбце вы хотите 5 нулей, затем 5 единиц и т.д. Эти числа получим из последовательности 0, 1, 2, ..., 18, 19 как целочисленное деление (`//`) числом 5 (т.е. отброся остаток).
4. Но и во втором столбце будет именно этот остаток (оператор `%` - деление по модулю, т.е. остаток от деления).

---

*Примечание:*

Функция `range(1, 21)` генерирует числа от 1 (включительно) до 21 (**не**включительно), т.е. числа 1, 2, 3, ...,19, 20 как вы, вероятно, хотели в последнем столбце.

Значит, как второй параметр нужно задать число на 1 больше, чем последнее желательное.

Comment: Проблема в том что мне нужно чтобы 0 0 1
0 1 2
0 2 3
0 3 4
0 4 5
1 0 6
1 1 7

Comment: Чтобы после 0 4 5 шло 1 0 6

Comment: порядок цифр не имеет значения может быть и 5 04 и 6 10

Comment: после 1 0 6 - 1 1 7 - 1 2 8 - 1 3 9

Comment: for i in range(0, 4):  # я не знаю, докуда вы хотите до (0, 4) or l in range(0, 5) до (0, 5)

Comment: @MerianD, Завершится 3 4 20

Answer (score 0):

Возможно также применить стандартную функцию [`divmod()`](https://pythobyte.com/python-divmod-function-15125db0/), которая одновременно возвращает как результат целочисленного деления, так и остаток — в виде пары
`(частное, остаток)`:

```
for i in range(1, 21):
    j, k = divmod(i, 5)
    print (j, k, i)
```